# MapView in lite mode causes RecyclerView to not scroll correctly

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm building a chat app in Android Studio with the abitily to send routes on a map. I've implemented this by using a RecyclerView and ViewHolders, which hold the necessary UI with MapViews in lite mode (`map:liteMode="true"`). Thing is, when I add a map UI element to the recyclerView and scroll to the end by using  `scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1)`, the scrolling has trouble following the views and is always slightly off, as seen on the screenshot
(https://i.postimg.cc/BvMzrHJL/Screenshot-20190526-005535.png).

Moreover, the keyboard gets confused about the height of the views as well when clicked (https://i.postimg.cc/Hs6BsHfR/Screenshot-20190526-011647.png).

I have tried switching lite mode off, but it makes the scrolling laggy and handling lifecycle events becomes an issue since my MapViews are in ViewHolders, not in Activities or Fragments, see official documentation:

> Users of this class [MapView] must forward all the life cycle methods from the 
>   Activity or Fragment containing this view to the corresponding ones in 
>   this class.

I have also tried changing the height of the layout from android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="250dp", but that also didn't work at all.

Also, scrolling works just fine with Views containing only text or an empty RelativeLayout istead of MapView.

I used this sample from Google's developer documentation https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LiteListDemoActivity.java

So here is my ViewHolder (one of two):

```
private class SentRouteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback
    {
        MapView sentMap;
        TextView routeSentTime;
        GoogleMap map;
        public SentRouteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            sentMap = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sent_map);
            routeSentTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.route_sent_time);
            sentMap.onCreate(null);
            sentMap.onResume();
            sentMap.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
            map = googleMap;
            setMapRoute();
        }
        void bind(Message message)
        {
            sentMap.setTag(message);
            setMapRoute();
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            routeSentTime.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(message.getTime()));
        }
        void setMapRoute()
        {
            if(map == null) return;
            Message message = (Message) sentMap.getTag();

            if(message==null) return;

            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        }

    }
```

And adding the item to the RecyclerView:

```
activeCollection.add(newMessage).addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {          
    documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
        adapter.addMessage(documentSnapshot);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.getItemCount());
        chatReycler.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount()-1);
    });
});
```

The `onBindViewHolder`:

```
SentRouteViewHolder routeViewHolder = (SentRouteViewHolder) viewHolder;
routeViewHolder.bind(message);
```

The `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.route_sent,parent,false);
Log.v("measure",String.valueOf(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
return new SentRouteViewHolder(v);
```

RecyclerView configuration:

```
    manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    chatReycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
    chatReycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    chatReycler.setHasFixedSize(false);
    chatReycler.setRecyclerListener(viewHolder -> {
        if(viewHolder.getItemViewType()==ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ROUTE_RECEIVED)
        {
            ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.ReceivedRouteViewHolder holder = (ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.ReceivedRouteViewHolder) viewHolder;
            if(holder.map!=null)
            {

                holder.map.clear();
                holder.map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            }
        }
        else if (viewHolder.getItemViewType()==ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ROUTE_SENT)
        {
            ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.SentRouteViewHolder holder = (ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.SentRouteViewHolder) viewHolder;
            if(holder.map!=null)
            {
                holder.map.clear();
                holder.map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

            }

        }
    });
```

The ViewHolder XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/route_received_background"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/message_received_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/received_map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/route_received_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/route_received_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/route_received_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/route_received_background"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:liteMode="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route_received_time"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/route_received_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/route_received_background"
        tools:text="11:50" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want the RecyclerView to scroll to the bottom of the sent map, and not to the middle of it. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with scrolling and checked that the parent layout was 0dp high. I changed it to match_parent and it worked.

```
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```